# How to have multiple conditions in list comprehension for 2d array

Tags: python, list, numpy, vector, list-comprehension

let `A = [3,4]`

and `Y` be an array of multiple values like

```
Y = [2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
X =
 [[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

then I want to select all those vectors of X where the corresponding X[Y] is in A. So I wrote the following code:

```
 Xij = [X[Y == j] for j in set(a)]
 print(Xij)
 print(shape(Xij))
```

Output:

```
 (3, 1, 1)
    [array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           ..., 
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           ..., 
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           ..., 
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

but this will lead a list of 2D array. I on other hand want a normal 2D array. 
I even tried with append function but that also doesn't seem to work

```
Xi = []
for j in A:
    m = [X[Y == j]]
    Xi.append([m])
```

Desired output:
instead of 3d array I got I want a normal 2d array appended together.

Any suggestion on how can I make this work?

Comment: updated the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got it working, there is a fucntion np.isin that did the job

```
Xij = X[np.isin(Y,A)]
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Thanks